# Failed fetch causes infinite component life-cycle loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

With a connected container, I have a reducer that is wrapped by a higher order reducer (show below) to catch and handle errors. When calling a fetch request during `componentDidMount` and it fails, the connected container will unmount itself `componentWillUnmount`. This causes an infinite loop in the container as it will mount again, fetch will fail, and container will unmount itself.

Any ideas why having the higher order reducer in the connect component is causing this?

Error handling higher order reducer:

```
export const errorHandler = (reducer: (state: any, action: { type: string }, initialState: any) => {}) => {
    const errorState = fromJS({
        error: {
            hasError: false,
            message: "",
        },
    });

    const initialState = errorState.merge(reducer(undefined, { type: undefined }, undefined));

    return (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ACTIONS.SET_ERROR:
                return state.setIn(["error", "hasError"], true)
                    .setIn(["error", "message"], action.message);

            case ACTIONS.CLEAR_ERROR:
                return state.set("error", errorState.get("error"));

            default:
                return reducer(state, action, initialState);
        }
    };
};
```

Example Container:

```
class Page extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetch(....);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.clearData();
        this.props.cancelRequests();
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state) => ({
        error: state.data.get("error", ""),
    }),
    {
        clearError,
        clearData,
        cancelRequests,
    },
)(Page);
```

Example Reducer:

```
export fetch = () => ({
   type: ACTIONS.FETCH
});

export default errorHandler((state, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
     default:
        return state;
   }
}));
```

Epic:

```
export const fetch = (action$: any, store: any, api: API) => {
    return action$.ofType(ACTIONS.FETCH)
        .mergeMap((action: any) =>
            fromPromise(api.fetch(action.data))
                .pluck("Data")
                .map(data) =>
                    fetchFulfilled(data),
                )
                .catch((response) => {
                    const toPromise = typeof response.json === "function" ? response.json() : new Promise((resolve) => resolve(response));

                    return fromPromise(toPromise)
                        .pluck("Message")
                        .map((Message: string) =>
                            setError(Message));
                })
                .takeUntil(action$.ofType(ACTIONS.CANCEL_REQUESTS)));
};
```

Comment: Typically components unmount because their parent no longer renders them. What does the parent of <Page> look like? (I'm actually not aware of any situation where a component can unmount itself, but perhaps it's possible)

Comment: This is exactly the issue. After looking into the issue more, I found a parent component that uses the same errorHandler() higher order reducer. Whenever setError() was being fired off, the parent would catch the event, and rerender its children (including Page here). Switching away from using the global setError() action fixed the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments:

Typically components unmount because their parent no longer renders them. What does the parent of  look like? It is likely where you would look to find why your component is unmounting.

I'm not aware of any situation where a component can unmount itself (without hacks)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need catch the error instead of letting the exception be caught by the React mounting code.

```
try {
   this.props.fetch(....);
}
catch (e) {
   //Do whatever is appropriate to handle the fetch failure. Maybe you want...
   this.setState({ error: {hasError: true, message: '' + e});
}
```

I think the setState() call above is not right for your intended reducer implementation, but that is a separate problem you can solve (or ask more questions about). The main part of your problem seemed to be stopping the unmount/remount behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I forgot to mention that I'm using Redux-Observable, so in this case `this.props.fetch()` is just dispatching an action--not doing the request. Unfortunately wrapping it in a try/catch doesn't work.

Example in original post has been updated.